# System.Globalization.CultureInfo (de)serialization

Tags: .net, serialization, deserialization, cultureinfo, lcid

I need to store a specific culture in a file. Is it enough to serialize the LCID integer or is that a lossy conversion? Is Name, NativeName or EnglishName to be preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `LCID` is enough to recreate the `CultureInfo`.

e.g.:

```
new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID)
```

...will create a new `CultureInfo` that is identical to the current one...

You could alternatively use the `Name` property:

```
new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)
```